# Browser compatibility window and document

Tags: javascript

I have this function

```
function getSwf(appName) {
    if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1)
        return window[appName];
    return document[appName];
}
```

But not sure if the last 2 lines are correct. I mean,

```
        return window[appName];
    return document[appName];
```

or

```
        return document[appName];
    return window[appName];
```

Comment: is this intened to support seriously ancient browser versions, or do you know something about the `document` and `window` objects that has passed me by?

Comment: nah, I just took that code from internet. Actually, I will just use jquery now `$('#theId').get(0)`.

Comment: fair enough. Just so you know, the correct syntax without jquery is `document.getElementByID('theId')`. This works in all browsers.

Comment: @SDC: `getElementById` (the `d` is lowercase). :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: of course  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to find a global variable, it's always on `window`.

If you're trying to find an HTML element with an `id`, on *most* browsers, it's always on `window`, but that behavior isn't (yet) the subject of an active specification; to be really sure, use `document.getElementById(appName)` instead, which will work on all browsers. (Firefox, for instance, doesn't put elements with `id`s on `window`.)

IE will also tend to throw elements with `name`s on `window`, even though `name` values aren't required to be unique. ***sigh*** Other browsers, thankfully, don't.